# How to use a variable in "LEFT()" function in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm afraid many would find this to be a dumb question...

```
@ECHO off
SET str=HelloWorld
ECHO.%str%
SET str=%str:~0,5%
ECHO %str%
```

The output is as expected:

```
HelloWorld
Hello
```

But this code below ...

```
@ECHO off
SET str=HelloWorld
ECHO.%str%
SET /A val=5
SET str=%str:~0,val%
ECHO.%str%
```

I'm intuitively expecting the same result but its output is strange to me.

```
HelloWorld
str:~0,val
```

Would anyone care to share why and how this can be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: `%str:~0,val%` is a syntax error because the shell expects a number there

Comment: Thank you @phuclv for your time. Yes, you are right about that error I called out. 
user2956477's contribution below is both helpful and informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `call`command which cause doubled set command execution. Variable `%val%` will evaluate in first set runtime which caused there will be a number in second runtime. Percent signs have to be doubled in this way `call SET str=%%str:~0,%val%%%`

Comment: Wow! Thank you @user2956477! You not only gave the fix but you VERY thoroughly explained it in very few words. Frankly, I didn't know about codes in scripts being evaluated in multiple runtimes and having the need to use 'call' for purposes like this. I learned something great today from you. I sincerely appreciate your time